# Mezzanine Pagedown embed a Youtube Video

Tags: django, python-3.x, youtube, markdown, mezzanine

Using Mezzanine with Pagedown I would like to embed a Youtube video. The only way I've been able to make this work is by removing `RICHTEXT_FILTERS` from `seetings.py` which obviously won't work

```
RICHTEXT_WIDGET_CLASS = 'mezzanine_pagedown.widgets.PageDownWidget'
RICHTEXT_FILTER = 'mezzanine_pagedown.filters.custom'
RICHTEXT_FILTERS = (RICHTEXT_FILTER,)
PAGEDOWN_MARKDOWN_EXTENSIONS = ('extra','codehilite','toc')
RICHTEXT_FILTER_LEVEL = 3 #changed from 3. This allows iframes.
PAGEDOWN_SERVER_SIDE_PREVIEW = True
```

Before you ask, this is a simple site and I am the only user. Readers don't need the ability to comment. XSS is not an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embedded videos are not supported by the standard markdown specification, or by the stock python-markdown converter.

There are two issues to consider when trying to support new content elements in `mezzanine-pagedown`:

1. The markdown converter (python-markdown) must recognize the element, typically through using an additional [custom python-markdown extension](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/api.html), which you can then add to the `PAGEDOWN_MARKDOWN_EXTENSIONS` setting. Alternatively, you can use [inline HTML](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) within your markdown documents.
2. The resulting HTML content after the conversion (or the inline HTML) must be legal as per the standard Mezzanine settings: `RICHTEXT_ALLOWED_TAGS`, `RICHTEXT_ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES`, and `RICHTEXT_ALLOWED_STYLES`. These settings are applied to the markdown-generated HTML by mezzanine-pagedown.